# Should I turn indexing of a hard drive on or off on Windows Server 2019 with a HDD with millions of files on it?

Tags: windows, iis, hard-drive, filesystems, windows-server-2019

Server is running Windows Server 2019 with IIS running.

I have a standard spindle enterprise 8TB HHD with about 30 million JPEG image files on it. The amount of images grows daily. Each file is less than 100K in size.

These files are accessed and viewed only via direct URL links and uploaded/overwritten by a PHP script accessed from our web service URL.

Should I turn the indexing of this entire hard drive on or off? Will that make direct access of the files, via both IIS and the PHP script, slower or faster?

Is indexing ONLY used for File Explorer search, or used within Windows as a deeper method to speeding up file access no matter which method is used?

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, I would disable windows file indexing. More precisely, as Windows Search is [disabled *by default* on Win2016/2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3204979/windows-search-is-disabled-by-default-in-windows-server-2016), I would left it disabled.

Windows Search creates a small database with data relative to your files. To get a fast search, an external application must explicitly support querying the Windows Search databases via the Windows API.